# What causes "Bad variable type." in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a value in an array which displays the value "Bad variable type." and the type "Variant" when viewed in IE debugger. What could cause this error?

The value should be a string and the only operation on that array item in the JavaScript is to copy it to the .firstChild.nodeValue of a page element.

simplified code example:

```
response = erHttp.responseText;
temp = response.split('^^');        
document.getElementById("page_element").firstChild.nodeValue = temp[0];
```

Comment: are you using a `for .. in` ?

Comment: @EuanC we need a full example that reproduces the error. What is the value of the AJAX response?

Comment: @Xeon06 thats part of the problem, the error is infrequent. The AJAX response is a series of values (ints, floats and strings) separated by the ^^ sequence passed into the split function. I assume something must be wrong with the response string but I haven't seen any corruption. What could cause this type of error in general?

Comment: @EuanC as far as I know, nothing. That's not in the specs. It's IE specific. That's why you need to try to isolate and be able to reproduce the error on demand for a fix to be proposed. I suggest you always print the the responseText and when the error happens, save it and try and reproduce it.

Comment: @Xeon06 thanks, I had not been able to find any information on this type of error. The error only occurs every 100,000 or so requests which means running the system for hours before it happens. I will do as you suggest and report back if I find the cause.

Comment: The problem here is that unless we know what's on the wire it's going to be impossible to answer this question. Also you don't tell us if you're making calls to the server synchronously or asynchronously. Does it only happen in IE, what about Chrome/Firefox. There's too many parts of the puzzle missing.

Comment: @Kev Calls are being made asynchronously. Primarily we are running with IE but I did run with Firefox last night with no failures, however it does not consistently fail every night with IE. A second system running over night with IE did fail and interestingly after detecting the failure I ran split on the response string again and the resulting buffer has no errors...

Answer (score 2):

In IE, "Variant" usually means you're working with ActiveX objects.  If the code is expecting a string, and your object can't be automagically stringified, of course it's gonna choke.

Given your comments above, i'm going to assume you're using an XMLHTTP object to get the data, and suggest that you check the `readyState` and `status` properties of the object before assuming you have a `responseText` to work with.

If you're already doing those checks and still getting intermittent errors (particularly if it's for 1 in 100k requests, and doubly so if you can repeat the exact same process with the exact same data and have it succeed), chances are it's either a bug in IE/Windows or a glitch specific to your machine.  I'm leaning toward the latter.

Comment: apologies for being too vague, I am new to stackoverflow and my last question got closed for being too specific! I tried to make this question more general in asking what the cause of a "Bad variable type" error, apparently this was too general :S.
You are correct in your assumption I am using an XMLHTTP object and we are already checking for readyState = 4 || "complete" and status = 200 before working with the responseText.